# WS_POPUP window behaves strangely when resized

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a window with the style `WS_POPUP` that can be resized through an `NCHITTEST`.  I am returning only the corner results (HTTOPLEFT, etc) so that the window cannot be dragged.  When the window is being resized, it sort of "wobbles" - that is, for a couple of frames the corner that isn't being resized changes its position until settling back to its previous one.

This seems to be some kind of default behavior, as this occurs whether or not I set the window position myself - IE, it happens if I'm just doing the NCHITTESTs.  It's not that big of a deal, as the window eventually settles to its correct coordinates, but it looks kind of unprofessional.  Is there something I can do to change this behavior?

Here is my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK wnd_proc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam);

INT16 x = 0;
INT16 y = 0;
WORD width = 0;
WORD height = 0;
HWND handle = NULL;
bool run = true;
INT16 desktop_x = 0;
INT16 desktop_y = 0;
WORD desktop_width = 0;
WORD desktop_height = 0;

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPWSTR, int) {
        const WNDCLASSEXW wc = {
                sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW),
                CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW,
                wnd_proc,
                0, 0, GetModuleHandleW(NULL),
                NULL,
                LoadCursorW(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_ARROW)),
                (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 2),
                NULL, L"DreamBeatWnd",
                NULL
        };

        RegisterClassExW(&wc);

        {
                RECT desktop = { 0 };

                GetWindowRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &desktop);

                desktop_x = desktop.left;
                desktop_y = desktop.top;
                desktop_width = desktop.right - desktop.left;
                desktop_height = desktop.bottom - desktop.top;
        }

        width = ((WORD)((desktop_width) * 0.80) / 16) * 16;
        height = (width / 16) * 9;
        x = desktop_x + ((desktop_width) / 2) - (width / 2);
        y = desktop_y + ((desktop_height) / 2) - (height / 2);

        handle = CreateWindowW(
                wc.lpszClassName,
                L"window",
                WS_POPUP,
                x, y,
                width, height,
                NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL
                );

        UpdateWindow(handle);
        ShowWindow(handle, SW_SHOW);

        MSG msg;

        while (true) {
                while (PeekMessageW(&msg, handle, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) > 0) {
                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
                }

                if (!run) {
                        break;
                }
        }

        return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK wnd_proc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
        switch (message) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
                run = false;
                return 0;

        case WM_NCHITTEST: {
                POINT p;
                p.x = LOWORD(lparam);
                p.y = HIWORD(lparam);
                ScreenToClient(window, &p);

                if (p.x < 3) {
                        if (p.y < 3) {
                                return HTTOPLEFT;
                        }
                        else if (p.y > height - 3) {
                                return HTBOTTOMLEFT;
                        }
                }
                else if (p.x > width - 3) {
                        if (p.y < 3) {
                                return HTTOPRIGHT;
                        }
                        else if (p.y > height - 3) {
                                return HTBOTTOMRIGHT;
                        }
                }

                return DefWindowProcW(window, message, wparam, lparam);
        }

        case WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING: {
                WINDOWPOS* pos = (WINDOWPOS*)(lparam);

                pos->cx = (int)((double(pos->cy) / 9) * 16);
                pos->x = (int)((double(desktop_x + desktop_width) / 2) - (double(pos->cx) / 2));
                pos->y = (int)((double(desktop_y + desktop_height) / 2) - (double(pos->cy) / 2));

                x = pos->x;
                y = pos->y;
                width = pos->cx;
                height = pos->cy;

                return 0;
        }
        }

        return DefWindowProcW(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any special handling for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` etc?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I do, but this happens even with that removed (leaving it up to DefWindowProc).

Comment: Maybe you could provide a SSCCE?

Comment: @JonathanPotter On it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter http://pastebin.com/bgBhvFuQ

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe (Win7 x64). What is your OS?

Comment: I think you can improve the situation by a clever implementation of the `WM_NCCALCSIZE` message. Unfortunately the documentation of this message is severely lacking...

Comment: @WernerHenze 8.1 - it's quite possible that it has something to do with the new compositing system.

Comment: @NmdMystery I also cannot reproduce the error when I run the program on a Windows 8.1 in a VirtualBox on my Windows 7. Or maybe I am misunderstanding what exactly the error is.

Comment: @WernerHenze If you resize the window, the opposite corner's coordinates change for a few frames before returning to their correct position, which is not normal behavior.